# Communication between Rasbperry and Arduino

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, chess

I'm trying to get a Chessboard from my Arduino to my Rasbperry by serial communication. In my Chess programm the board is defined:

```
self.board = 
[['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR'],
 ['bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp'],
 ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
 ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
 ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
 ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
 ['wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp'],
 ['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR']]
```

and like this the Board works well and loads. But i want to get the Board information from the Arduino by:

```
   def brett(self):
        
            ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)
            ser.flush()
            while True:
                if ser.in_waiting > 0:
                    Brett = [ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()]
                    return Brett   

    def __init__(self):

        self.board = self.brett()
...
```

Here Brett is my board and form the Arduino I get:

```
['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR'],
['bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp'],
['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR']
```

Exactly the Board no? Somehow I cannot run the Chessboard, somebody has any clue why it doesnt work like this, or what I could do, to get it to work? Is it overall possible to do something like this?
The error i receive at the moment is:

```
string index out of Range
end_piece = self.board[end_row][end_col]
```

I think its still because self.board doesnt take the array from my Arduino, because when i use the array as in the first part, the string is not out of Range.

edit:
The Arduino code is really simple, i just wanted to get the Array as an Input firstly:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  Serial.println("['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR'],['bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp'],['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],['wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp'],['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR']");
  delay(1000000000);
}
```

this is the part of the code, where the error starts, but i dont think it will be usefull, since the code works when i write the array.

```
    def checkForPinsAndChecks(self):
        pins = []  # squares pinned and the direction its pinned from
        checks = []  # squares where enemy is applying a check
        in_check = False
        if self.white_to_move:
            enemy_color = "b"
            ally_color = "w"
            start_row = self.white_king_location[0]
            start_col = self.white_king_location[1]
        else:
            enemy_color = "w"
            ally_color = "b"
            start_row = self.black_king_location[0]
            start_col = self.black_king_location[1]
        # check outwards from king for pins and checks, keep track of pins
        directions = ((-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1))
        for j in range(len(directions)):
            direction = directions[j]
            possible_pin = ()  # reset possible pins
            for i in range(1, 8):
                end_row = start_row + direction[0] * i
                end_col = start_col + direction[1] * i
                if 0 <= end_row <= 7 and 0 <= end_col <= 7:
                    end_piece = self.board[end_row][end_col]
```

I'm sorry, I'm new to programming and this is my Project.
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: How did you get what you got from the arduino? print? if yes then what have you printed? You didn't show the part of the code where it errors out, where is  `end_piece = self.board[end_row][end_col]` where do you get end_row end_col from?
try print(self.board,self.board[-1][-1])

Comment: @zx485 Im sorry i didnt want to change all the edits, or actually i dont know if i did. I just saw that i made a mistake in writing the code here, where there was a ',' too much at the end. Then it wouldnt be the same array, so i removed it quick

Comment: @AdamSałata thank you for your help. I dont think the error is in the code, i think its an error from the serial communication, since if i write the array like this: self.board = 
[['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR'],
 ['bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp'],
 ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
 ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
 ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
 ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
 ['wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp'],  **

Comment: ** 
 ['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR']], everything works fine. And im not 100% sure where end_row/col comes from, i thought its an implemented feature that it detect the end row/col of the array. Maybe its from Pygame. Where should i try to print(self.board,self.board[-1][-1])  ? just like this so i can see if it even receives the board as self.board?

Comment: Oh, so the problem is that you are not acually receiving a 2d list but a string that looks like a representation of a 2d list, I suggest sending the board state in FEN notation, this will be way easier to encode actual board data and decode them after receiveng them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation As for decoding FEN I suggest using .split('/') and iterating over this array and iterating over the chars in current row

Comment: @AdamSałata: I have to admit that this misunderstanding may be due to my reformatting of the question's strings. Mea culpa. (See revision history)